# How does Material Exchange work?

Tags: destiny

I have the option of trading in some Spirit Bloom (or any of the other materials—Spinmetal, Helium Filaments, Relic Iron) with the Crucible Quartermaster (I believe some other vendor does it too), but it gives me no indication what I'd get in exchange. I imagine it's some amount of rep and perhaps marks, but what is it? And if it's variable, what are its deciding factors? Do all kinds of elements have the same conversion rate?

**Note:** As of the [December 1st update](http://www.bungie.net/7_Destiny-Update---12012014/en/News/News?aid=12433) material exchanges now work in the opposite direction, where marks are used to purchase materials.

What is the exchange rate for marks to materials?

Comment: you'll get rep for sure, and maybe marks. since I can't remember exactly (and don't have enough to trade in) I won't put an actual answer int... also when you get purple and higher gear you'll need those resources to level them up, but you don't really need to hoard them for later as you'll probably find lots if you do patrol missions regularly

Comment: You still cannot get more than the capped 100 marks per week, even if you do material exchange.

Comment: 75k views :O crazy!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use 10 legendary marks to purchase 20 of any planetary material from the Vanguard Quartermaster.  See below to locate the quartermaster.

Faction rep (per each of the 3 factions: Dead Orbit, Future War Cult, New Monarchy) can be gained by speaking to the respective faction rep in the tower, as seen on the below map.  The exchange rates are as follows, gaining rep for the faction rep you exchange with:

> 5 Motes -> 100 rep
>
> 25 Weapon Parts -> 50 rep
>
> 25 Old Armor Materials✝ -> 50 rep
>
> 25 Unified Armor Materials -> 50 rep
>
> Special Ammo Synth -> 25 rep
>
> Heavy Ammo Synth -> 25 rep

✝ *Old Armor Materials includes Plasteel Plating, Sapphire Wire, and Hadronic Essence.*

---

**EDIT**: The below exchanges are no longer valid as of "The Taken King", September 2015.

You can now go to the Vanguard/Crucible Quartermaster and exchange 10 marks for:

> 20 Spinmetal
>
> 20 Helium Filaments
>
> 20 Spirit Bloom
>
> 20 Relic Iron

[image]

The Crucible Quartermaster is in the middle area of the tower before the class Vanguards (opposite Lord Shaxx).  On the map this is in the blue area near the icon that says Crucible.

The Vanguard Quartermaster is in the area near the shipwright.  On the map this is in the red area and marked Quartermaster.

---

**EDIT:** The below is no longer true as a of a patch in late 2014.

> Each time you exchange 50 of each material to either the Crucible or
>   Vanguard Quartermaster, you get:
>
> > +5 Crucible/Vanguard Marks (as long as you're below the weekly limit)
> >
> > +25 Crucible/Vanguard Reputation (these change if you have a faction class armor equipped)
> >
> > +250 Glimmer
>
> Note that you are also capped at 200 total marks for each faction, and
>   100 per week for each faction.

Comment: Please note that class items for different factions influence the reputation gains, hence, you might gain reputation for different factions. Furthermore, exchanging materials won't reward you with marks once you have hit your weekly limit. Also, the exchange rewards Glimmer!

Comment: @EricTobias good details, updated

Comment: Note that as of the December patch, this trade-in effect is no longer relevant. Trades now function in the opposite direction marks -> materials.

Comment: Good job on keeping this uptodate and relevant.

Answer (score 2):

These answers are all from before the end-of-year patch.  Now, materials exchange only works the other way: you can *buy* materials, but you can't sell them.

Comment: What can you do with the materials now then? I haven't seen anywhere to spend them.

Comment: The materials are now only used to upgrade equipment (which was also the case pre-patch) but you can no longer trade in excess materials you may have acquired

Comment: @DannyBeckett, I feel your pain.  But RobV is completely correct: you will need the materials to upgrade weapons and armor.

Comment: @CPerkins Ah, legendary and exotics right? Not quite there yet... level 26.

Answer (score 0):

You also get 250 Glimmer for each 50 Material...and 5 Marks, and 25 Reputation, as satated.

I think if you wear a Faction Mark/Bon/Cloak the marks/rep gain goes to that faction instead of Vangurd/Crucible.
Not sure though, I haven't tried it.
Though I do know doing Patrol Missions with a Faction Item worn gives the reputation reward to the faction you are wearing.

Comment: It does swap reputation to the faction you are wearing the item for.

Answer (score 0):

I traded in 50 spin metal and got one mote of light. 50 spirit bloom and got 250 glimmer 5 crucible marks and 25 rep.

Comment: Really..? The most I have *ever* got from a trade in was 50 Vanguard rep/Crucible rep. Who are you trading with? What level are you? What Vanguard/Crucible level are you?

Comment: The mote of light may have come at a level up point for the mote of light.